# How would you "Normalize" this SQL?

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

So, I will have a table called "REPS". In that table I will have this info.

```
ID

NAME

ZIP_CODES
```

I need to figure out how I should do the ZIP_CODES section. Should it be JSON format of zip codes? Like this

```
zip_codes('{"32343", "324234", "34234"}')
```

Then if I want to grab the name where ZIP matches any of them in ZIP_CODES? Or should ZIP_CODES have it's own table?

Comment: It's confusing because one rep may be associated with 10+ zip codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having a table of zip codes and a table of reps.  Then create a map table of sorts that has its own ID, the rep ID, and then the zip code ID.

Table zipcode

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
name VARCHAR(64)
zipcode VARCHAR(15)  // account for postal codes from Canada etc
```

Table rep

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
name VARCHAR(64)
```

Table rep_zipcode_map

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
zipcode_id INT
rep_id INT
```

Then if you wanted the list of zip codes serviced by a rep, you could service this request with a simple JOIN.

An alternative approach would be to use a graph database of sorts.  Sounds like it may be the right approach for this problem.

Comment: What is the NAME column in the Table ZIPCODE for though?

Comment: It's arbitrary, perhaps you could use it for a city name or something.  Can be removed.